# How to install / start neo4j on mac?

Tags: macos, neo4j, installation

I tried to install neo4j on mac / Maverics in two ways:

1) Download zip from http://www.neo4j.org/ meantime I installed JDK 8.

```
$ /Users/xx/Downloads/neo4j-community-2.1.2/bin/neo4j-installer install
WARNING: this installer is deprecated and may not be the optimal way to install Neo4j on your system.
  Please see the Neo4j Manual for up to date information on installing Neo4j.
Press any key to continue
```

2) Then I installed it with Homebrew, it was successfull, but when I try to start:

```
$ neo4j start
Another server-process is running with [311], cannot start a new one. Exiting.
$ neo4j stop
ERROR: Neo4j Server not running
$ neo4j status
Neo4j Server is not running
$ neo4j install
Legacy install now lives in the 'neo4j-installer' script
```

What is the problem, how to install / start?

## UPDATE

Server with PID 311 was java. So I just killed it, and start it over, now works. It is the normal way handling the issue?

```
$ kill 311
$ /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.2/bin/neo4j start
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew -Djava.awt.headless=true
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [1748]... waiting for server to be ready....... OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
```

Comment: "Server with PID 311 was java". What do you mean exactly by "java"?

Comment: I opened Monitor and I scrolled down to PID 311, and a process called java, without any other info was there.

Comment: Hmmm ok. So as I answered, my guess is this is totally specific to your setup, not something you usually have to do.

Comment: I have done nothing specific during installation process, I have a standard mac, as it was recommended I installed JDK 8, I do not understand why is an installation process so complicated

Comment: Well, the installation is actually pretty straightforward. You just happened to have a conflicting executing process, *that* is the specific part of *your* setup. Unfortunately, we could not get more information about this process. It really usually does not happen.

Comment: This happens to me too. Each time there’s a problem I have to quit the Java process and restart the server. I haven’t changed any preferences and am using a mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the issue you faced was just due to your particular local setup.

Comment: Yep, duplicate conflicting install. Either binary download or homebrew

Answer (score 19):

It is easier to use: `brew install neo4j`

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays it can also be installed using Docker:

```
docker run \
       --publish=7474:7474 \
       --publish=7687:7687 \
       --name neo4j \
       --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
       neo4j:3.3
```

Note the `3.3` at the end of the command. You can change it to run another version of Neo4j. Take a look here for the list of available versions: https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j?tab=tags